# How does ghc know which definition of fmap, etc. to use?

Tags: haskell, types

I know that `fmap` has type `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` where `f` is a functor (and does different things depending on what the functor is). My basic question is this: given some invocation `fmap r x`, how does ghc figure out what the functor `f` is, just given the types of `x` and `r`?

Let me make this more precise. Suppose `f` and `f'` are functors such that `f a` = `f' a` for some type `a`, but `f b` and `f' b` are different. If `r` has type `a -> b` and `x` has type `f a`, it seems there are two different possible results for `fmap r x`: something of type `f b` and something of type `f' b`. How is this ambiguity resolved?

A secondary question: I wanted to test this out by making a weird functor -- maybe something that takes `a` to `[Int]` for any type `a` and does something stupid to functions... but I apparently haven't found the right bit of syntax that allows me to specify functors this way. (Is there something like `data Newtype a = [Int]` that works? It seems I'd need to make a typeclass name before I can make it an instance of functor.)

EDIT: I get it now, but for the record, the real issue (which is only implicit in my question) was that I didn't realize you can't have a functor `Foo` such that `Foo a` is a type like `Int` that already exists.

Comment: Aren't typeclasses the thing you're looking for?

Comment: Concrete implementations of `fmap` for some `Foo a` are described in `instance Functor <Foo>` for typeclass `Functor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell type classes are based on first-order logic resolution.  A type class constraint on a type variable is a predicate (you may have seen error messages indicating this if you ever tried to use a type class name where a type name was required) in that logic system.

Haskell requires a unique solution for each (Predicate, Type) pair throughout the program, so you will not be able to create two different Functor instances over Int, for example.  The standard way around this, such as in the Monoid class for numeric types that could provide either a summation or product depending on how you define the monoidal operator you want to use, is to provide `newtype` wrappers over the concrete type that you want the class to have different instances for.

So, for `Monoid`, we have `newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }` and `instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a)` for the sum monoid and `newtype Product a = Product { getProduct :: a }` and `instance Num a => Monoid (Product a)` for the product monoid.

Note that since `type` only creates an alias for a type, it's not sufficient to provide multiple class instances for a type.  The `newtype` declaration is like `type` in the sense that it does not produce any additional run-time structure for the new type, but it is unlike `type` in that it creates a new type rather than a type alias.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general answer you're looking for is that Haskell types are organized using "kinds", which are like types of types.

Here's the `Functor` class

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It's not explicit, but this means that `f` is a type constructor with kind `* -> *`.  Only types with that kind can be made `Functor`s.

This is actually a rather strong statement.  It means that any `Functor` must be parametric in a type argument.  Now consider your statement:

> Suppose f and f' are functors such that f a = f' a for some type a,
>   but f b and f' b are different.

Given the kind system, this isn't possible.  Since a `Functor` is parametric in its type argument, `f a = f' a` implies `f = f'`, therefore `f b = f' b`.

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for with the "weird functor", but it sounds like something that couldn't be expressed with the `Functor` type class.  IIRC `Functor` can only express endofunctors on Hask; you may need a different abstraction that allows for functors between categories.

Comment: As I see it (math notation, not haskell), a functor f is a set map ob(Hask) -> ob(Hask) (where ob(Hask) is the objects of the category Hask, i.e. the set of all haskell types), along with an implementation of fmap. You claim that if `f a` = `f' a` for *any* type a, then `f = f'`. But, ignoring the fmap thing for a second, it's perfectly reasonable to have two maps of sets f,f': ob(Hask) -> ob(Hask) that have the same value on some types but not others (e.g. if there were only 5 types a,b,c,d,e then you could have maps f,f':{a,b,c,d,e} -> {a,b,c,d,e} such that f(a) = f'(a) but f(b) != f'(b).

Comment: In category theory, at least, the thing I'm asking for -- a functor sending any type to the type [Int], that sends every function a->b to the identity [Int] -> [Int] -- is definitely a valid endofunctor Hask -> Hask. Maybe you're trying to tell me that not every endofunctor Hask -> Hask is something you can actually construct in haskell?

Comment: @jm109: There are many valid endofunctors on `Hask`, but the `Functor` type class only covers a small fraction of them. The restrictions placed on the head of instance declaration (namely no type families and no partially applied type synonyms) let you assume that `f a = f a' => f = f'`.

Comment: @Vitus: where exactly can I find these restrictions?

Comment: @jm109: Just the usual Haskell 2010 stuff: type class instances must look like `instance (context) => c (f a1 a2 a3 ... an)`, where `c` is the type class, `f` is a type constructor and `a1` to `an` are distinct type variables.

Comment: @jm109: The key thing to realize is that `f` and `f'` must be type constructors. Type constructors have the property that `f a` is different from any other type that doesn't mention `f`, this gives you `f /= f' => f a /= f' a`.

Comment: @Vitus: OK, is this roughly correct -- the only way to make functors is by using type constructors e.g. `data Foo a = ...` and by nature of type constructors, `Foo a` can't be a type that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what argument you pass it.  For example a list is a functor and so is `Maybe`

```
main = do
   putStrLn $ show (double [1..5])
   putStrLn $ show (double (Just 3))
   putStrLn $ show (double Nothing)

double :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f a
double = fmap (*2)

*Main> main
[2,4,6,8,10]
Just 6
Nothing
```

This `double` function will work for any functor that is holding an `Num`.

Answer (score 0):

"Suppose `f` and `f'` are functors such that `f a` = `f' a` for some type `a`, but `f b` and `f' b` are different."

This doesn't really make sense. Either `f` and `f'` are the same, or they aren't. You seem to be suggesting some kind of in-between state where it varies depending on the argument type; that can't happen.

"If `r` has type `a -> b` and `x` has type `f a`, it seems there are two different possible results for `fmap r x`: something of type `f b` and something of type `f' b`. How is this ambiguity resolved?"

Where did `f'` come from? Nothing in the above signatures mentions it. Since `x` has type `f a`, it follows that the result of `fmap` must have some type beginning with `f` - in this case `f b`, since `r :: a -> b`. This is perfectly unambiguous. The result of `fmap` is *always* in the same functor as you started with.

Comment: `f'` in your second quote from my question was supposed to be the same as the `f'` in the first quote. `f` and `f'` are basically functions that take some type and return some other type (plus having fmap defined); so just like (in math) I can have two set functions f,f': {a,b,c} -> {a,b,c} such that f(a) = f'(a) but f(b) != f'(b), why can't I have a pair of functors f,f' such that f a = f' a but f b != f' b?

Comment: @jm109 f and f' are *not* arbitrary type level functions. They are type constructors. As such, each is a functor from Hask to a *distinct subcategory of Hask*.

Comment: @jm109 In fact, type constructors are faithful/injective, and as Ben points out, have disjoint images. If `f a` = `f' b` then `f` = `f'` and `a` = `b`. For example, `[Int]` cannot equal `Maybe Char`, because if it did, then `Int`=`Char` and `[]`=`Maybe`.